# How to send string of data from one android device to another?

Tags: android, chat, google-cloud-messaging

I need to implement a simple messaging functionality in my app . Two users who have installed my app should be able to  message each other inside/outside my app  . It doesnt need to be real time like a chat app. A bit of latency is acceptable . Should I implement this using a central server and a Google Cloud Messaging service like UrbanAirPush ?  Or Should I use socket programming(not very familiar with this ,but I dont mind learning) .

Also , I dont want to use SMS or bluetooth for this . Please advise me on the correct approach to this . UrbanAirpush has a limit , So any other option would be wonderful .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a free web service in [cross-copy](http://cross-copy.net)
You can use [this](https://github.com/rodja/cross-copy/blob/master/README.md) api as a guide

or just [Google](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer . I would like to know if cross-copy.net uses GCM too ? Because I want to implement something like this on my own .Do you have any pointers on how to go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use wifi direct or Network service discovery. 
Use wifip2p can allow you easily send message/audio/picture to other device nearby, you can check this tutorial: [WIFI DIRECT](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html), the NSD is also list there. You can even find sample codes(WIFIServiceDiscoveryActivty) from Android SDK to check some more information.